# How do i create a category and subcategories

Tags: python, django

This is my Item Model, how do i create a Category and Subcategories like; Man-clothing-shirt and Woman-clothing-shirt.

```py
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    product_you_may_like = models.ForeignKey(ProductYouMayLike, null=True, blank=True, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    old_price = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    shipping_amount = models.IntegerField()
    percentage_off = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    specification = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    product_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=PRODUCT_TYPE, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', unique=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-timestamp']
        db_table = 'items'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Items'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by adding a model Category and also A foreignkey to Item model. Example,

```
class Item(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,     null=True,blank=True,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

In model add men_shirt in Category, then save.

In views.py:

```
def template(request):
    category = Category.objects.filter(name="men_shirt")
    context = { 'category':category } 
    return render(request, "template.html", context)
```

In template:

```
{% for category in category %} 
{% for item in category.item.all %}
 <h1>This will display all content in item by the name you filtered in views.py </h1>
{% endfor %} 
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may make use of [django-mptt](https://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/overview.html) to create a tree of categories and then have a foreign-key to this model in the item model.

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=75,null=False,blank=False, unique=True)
    parent=TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I implement this in views.py and template For example I want to get only Man shirt category. How do I do this?

Comment: You can also check https://django-treebeard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you wrote your `MenShirtCategory`, but the name let me think that you mixed up class and instance.

Usually, you may have a `Category` model (or `ItemCategory`, if these caterogies are specific to `Item`) written this way:

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=..., ...)  # men shirts will be the name
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True,
                               on_delete=...,
                               related_name='children')
```

And then connect it to your Item model:

```py
class Item(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, blank=True,
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

By using `'self'` in the `parent` field of the `Category` model, you can implement the concept of nested categories.

Of course, you may need to ensure manually that you don't create cycles (A child of B child of A), as the database (and then models) cannot do it for you. While doing this, you may also need to check that a category cannot be it's own parent.

Comment: How to I implement this in views.py and template?

Comment: i am able to get item in category, how do i pass the parent in template. For example i have to display the man shirt in template and also the woman shirt in template, how do i get this from model? I tried something like this in template.
{% for category in category %}
  <h2>{{ item.name }}</h2>
   {% for item in category.item_set.all %}
<p>{{ item.title }}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
I was able to get only item in category, i added men wear and women wear in Category but could not get only the men wear in Category.
My views.py. 
category = Category.objects.all()
@mistiru